# Get users for all accounts with Google Analytics api

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I am having problems getting a list of users for accounts

If I put the account number in the try me page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/list) it works

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_MANAGE_USERS);

$client=gaGetClient();
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
     $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
     $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
     //this doesn't work
     $accountUserlinks=$analytics->management_accountUserLinks->listManagementAccountUserLinks('123456');
     //this works
     $man_accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
      $accounts = [];
      foreach ($man_accounts['items'] as $account) {
           $accounts[] = [ 'id' => $account['id'], 'name' => $account['name'] ];
           echo $account['name'] . " (" . $account['id'] . ")<br/>";
      }
}
```

I get this error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with
>   message 'Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/123456/entityUserLinks:
>   (403) Insufficient Permission' in
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62):
>   Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request),
>   Object(Google_Client)) #1 [internal function]:
>   Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client),
>   Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46):
>   Google_Task_Runner->run() #4
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Goo
>   in
>   /home/grant/www/productaudit.hcpservices.co.uk/htdocs/current/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php
>   on line 110

Can anyone think what I am doing wrong.  I am thinking it is a scope issue, but I have stated my scopes

Thanks

Grant

Comment: I am thinking the user you are currently authenticating with doesn't have access to that info?

Comment: I create the api access file and am using that.  I can see the Analytics api is enabled, is there some other permission I should be interested in?

Comment: What do you mean by "create the api access file"?    What ever user you used to create that access_token must have permissions to see the users probably be the owner I would assume.

Comment: I meant here https://console.developers.google.com.  I created a project and added in the analytics api, it then gave me a json file that I use here - $client->setAuthConfigFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/client_secrets.json'); - is that the wrong way to do this?

Comment: OK it has nothing to do with that the google developer console file just identifies your application it has nothing to do with the permissions granted by the authenticated user..   The user you authenticated with gives you $_SESSION['access_token']) if that user doesn't have access then you cant see it.